# How do you query an embedded document in MongoDB returning a subset of results?

Tags: mongodb, lithium

I've got a data structure like so:

```
Post
{
'id': $_id,
'user' : ['first_name' : 'Joe', 'last_name' : 'Devon' ],
'text' : 'blah',
'comment' : 
  ['first' : 'Joe', 'last' : 'Devon', 'comment' : 'hello'],
  ['first' : 'John', 'last' : 'Smith', 'comment' : 'bye', 'hidden' : true],
  ['first' : 'Joe', 'last' : 'Devon', 'comment' : 'world']
},
{
'id': $_id,
'user' : ['first_name' : 'Joe', 'last_name' : 'Shmoe' ],
'text' : 'meh',
'comment' : 
  ['first' : 'Joe', 'last' : 'Devon', 'comment' : 'sup'],
},
{
'id': $_id,
'user' : ['first_name' : 'Mr.', 'last_name' : 'Smith' ],
'text' : 'bah',
'comment' : 
  ['first' : 'Joe', 'last' : 'Devon', 'comment' : 'sup mon'],
}
```

I'm trying to run a query that will return everything EXCEPT the comment that has 'hidden':true.

Tried everything that doesn't work. Looking for the one command that will work. Help please :)

Comment: Command of what? MongoDB commandline client?

Comment: Eventually I will try to make it work in Lithium, but I like to break down the problem into getting the query to even work on the command line as I couldn't even do that.

Comment: It's important to remember you can only ever query for top level documents. If you need what you're trying to do then comments should never be embedded. The only route you can take to somewhat preserve your schema is to make a "comment" and "hiddenComment" field and populate them accordingly. You can move comments from and to their appropriate arrays with a single atomic update.

Comment: Thanks @RemonvanVliet. Still a brand newbie @ Mongo. Didn't know that. Now I have a good working rule to help decide on a schema. Very helpful.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet, is that really entirely true? I'm at the beginning of MongoDB: The Definitive Guide, and on page 53, there's a page and a half on querying embedded documents. Granted my query above doesn't work, but there does seem to be some support.

Comment: You cannot query *for* embedded documents. Meaning, the resultset cannot consist of anything but (optionally field filtered) top level documents. What the documentation is probably referring to is querying *on* embedded documents meaning using embedded document field in your query criteria.

Comment: Well I want top level documents returned! With the comments. Except for the "hidden" comments. So that's why I thought using an embedded document field in the query criteria would work.

Comment: I think I finally "got" what you guys are saying. Querying the embedded documents helps decide *which* "documents" are returned, but not which of the embedded documents therein are returned. But filtering that on the client side isn't usually a big deal for most situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently impossible to do with mongodb and you will have to filter comments on the client side.

The filtering mechanisms only serve to match or not match whole documents and then retrieve a subset of their fields but unfortunately you can't specify criteria for which of those to return.

If you had a collection for comments you could filter out the ones that have `hidden: true`.